# Creating structs in an array using Hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, twitter, struct, hive

I am creating table in hive for twitter json file.This is the sample file. The problem i am facing is that i am not able to create an array with struct because in the below data there are 4 same structs in a single array. Can anyone tell how can i create array for below data. I have tried giving each struct different name, the table was created successfully but i was not able to pull data from table.Kindly Help .
Thanks

```
> "variants": [
         {
           "bitrate": 2176000,
           "content_type": "video\/mp4",
           "url": "https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/560070131976392705\/pu\/vid\/1280x720\/c4E56sl91ZB7cpYi.mp4"
         },
         {
           "bitrate": 320000,
           "content_type": "video\/mp4",
           "url": "https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/560070131976392705\/pu\/vid\/320x180\/nXXsvs7vOhcMivwl.mp4"
         },
         {
           "bitrate": 832000,
           "content_type": "video\/webm",
           "url": "https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/560070131976392705\/pu\/vid\/640x360\/vmLr5JlVs2kBLrXS.webm"
         },
         {
           "bitrate": 832000,
           "content_type": "video\/mp4",
           "url": "https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/560070131976392705\/pu\/vid\/640x360\/vmLr5JlVs2kBLrXS.mp4"
         },
         {
           "content_type": "application\/x-mpegURL",
           "url": "https:\/\/video.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video\/560070131976392705\/pu\/pl\/r1kgzh5PmLgium3-.m3u8"
         }
       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
CREATE TABLE complex_json (
  variants:array<struct<bitrate:int,content_type:string, url:string>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';
```

get serde from https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Comment: Table is created but when i put run this query after loading the json data "SELECT extended_entities.media.video_info.variants.bitrate FROM f_t_tweets;" it throws this error "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10042]: Line 1:7 . Operator is only supported on struct or list of struct types 'bitrate'"